# Imbalanced Dataset leads to worse results after using balancing methods

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes

I have a very imbalanced Dataset. It's a binary classification.
In the train set I have 150,000 times class 0 and 500 times class 1. That's about 0.33%

When I train a model like DecisionTree I get a f1-score of ~0,011 in several runs.

I've read that I could use methods for balancing an imbalanced dataset. So I did. I used SMOTE, undersampling and oversampling on the train set from the imbalanced-learn API. But the results get worse:

- Smote f1-score: 0
- oversampling f1-score: 0
- undersampling f1-score: 0.001

My procedure summarized:

1. load data
2. split data in train (0.7) & test (0.3) set
3. use one or none of the balancing methods on the train set.
4. Train Decision Tree and compute f1-score with test set

Looking only at the results, I would prefer to do the parameter optimizing and feature selection without a balancing method.

How do you see that? Do I have an error? Am I wrong? I would appreciate any information. I am still quite a beginner.

Thank you very much.

Comment: when you do the train-test split do you use random or stratified splits? That might have a sizaable impact on the latter balancing methods.

Comment: Unbalanced classes are almost certainly not a problem, and oversampling will not solve a non-problem: [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352) Do not use accuracy to evaluate a classifier: 
[Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) Every critique against accuracy applies equally to the F1 score.

Comment: I make the train-test split manually. The data was measured over time on different people. The data from one person must not be in the training set and the test set, so I don't have an information leakage.
For example :
Training: Person 1, Person 2, Person 3, and Person 5.
Test: Person 4. ||


Okay, so it's seems it is not a problem, that the score is better without any imbalance-method. Thank you. ||

I also checked with roc_auc_score another metrics. But the tendency is the same